# How to point domain to port of the server AWS?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have AWS instance On which I had installed Ngix on 8080 port for `"app.xyz.com"` (Developed on ROR) and Apache on 80 Pot for `xyz.com` (developed on PHP).

I have set Route53 for domain and subdomain.

Now `"xyz.com"` works fine but for ROR its dons't work with just `"app.xyz.com"` but its works with `"app.xyz.com:8080"`.

Is there any way to point app.xyz.com to (Server IP with port 8080) 192.168.1.23:8080 , I tried to add  192.168.1.23:8080 directly  in value section in record set in Route 53( Please refer https://www.screencast.com/t/KjgPKeP7D ) but its doesn't work.

Anyone can let me know what is best way to point xyz.com on Apache and app.xyz.com on Nigix with 8080 port ?

Comment: you can point sites in `Nginx` by editing `etc/nginx/sites-available/default
` or add an new point

Comment: You can't point a domain to a port. You can only point a domain to an IP address. On the server you need to configure Apache to proxy requests for app.xyz.com to port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

You can write config for app.xyz.com in apache and setup reverse proxy to call port 8080.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension